# Azure Database ingestion speed

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to improve the ingestion speed in Azure SQL. Even though I'm using SQLAlchemy connection pool, the speed doesn't increase at all after certain number of threads and stuck at about 700 inserts per second.

Azure SQL shows 50% resource utilization. The code runs within Azure, so network shouldn't be an issue.

Is there a way to increase the speed?

```
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

def connect():
    return pyodbc.connect('....')

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://', creator=connect, pool_recycle=20, pool_size=128, pool_timeout=30)
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


def process_entry(i):
  session = scoped_session(session_factory)

  # skipping logic for computing vec, name1, name2
  # vec - list of floats, name1, name2 - strings
  vec = [55.0, 33.2, 22.3, 44.5]
  name1 = 'foo'
  name2 = 'bar'

  for j, score in enumerate(vec):  
    parms = {'name1': name1, 'name2': name2, 'score': score }
    try:
      session.execute('INSERT INTO sometbl (name1, name2, score) VALUES (:name1, :name2, :score)', parms)
      session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
      print(e)



fs = []
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=128)

for i in range(0, N):
  future = pool.submit(process_entry, i)
  fs.append(future)

concurrent.futures.wait(fs, timeout=None, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`commit()`ing every row imposes a wait for the row to be saved to the log file and possibly a secondary replica.  Instead commit every N rows.  Something like:

```
  rn = 0
  for j, score in enumerate(vec):  
    parms = {'name1': name1, 'name2': name2, 'score': score }
    try:
      session.execute('INSERT INTO sometbl (name1, name2, score) VALUES (:name1, :name2, :score)', parms)
      rn = rn + 1
      if rn%100 == 0:
        session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
      print(e)
  session.commit()
```

If you want to load data even faster, you can send JSON documents containing batches of data and parse and insert them in bulk using the [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function in SQL Server.  There are also special bulk loading APIs, but AFAIK these aren't easily accessible from python.

You'll also probably hit maximum throughput at a modest number of workers.  Unless your table is [Memory Optimized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-2017) it's likely that your inserts will need to coordinate access to shared resources, like latching the leading page in a BTree, or row locks in secondary indexes.

The high level of concurrency you currently have is probably just (partially) compensating for the current per-row commit strategy.

Comment: I've discovered that top tiers only offer 32GB of storage for memory optimized tables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-dtu-resource-limits  How would you deal with this when you have ten times more data?

Comment: The limit is 131GB on the biggest Gen5 VCore configs.  But in any case I'd probably use a clustered Columnstore.  You get a simple BTree for the new rows, and each 1M rows gets compressed into columnar storage (with an optional delay).  Columnstore doesn't have the lock-free, latch-free behavior of Memory Tables, but it's a better format for large volumes of data.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database size, you may consider to scale up to premium tiers during this IO intensive workloads to speed up things, and once they finish you may consider scale back to the original tier.

You may also consider using batching to improve performance. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-use-batching-to-improve-performance)  you will find how to use batching and other strategies to improve Insert performance like SqlBulkCopy, UpdateBatchSize, etc.

For the fastest insert performance, follow these general guidelines but test your scenario:

- For < 100 rows, use a single parameterized INSERT command.
- For < 1000 rows, use table-valued parameters.
- For >= 1000 rows, use SqlBulkCopy.